# How to batch update all symlink pointers to replace "_F-ss" with empty string?

Tags: sed, xargs, readlink

I am trying to replace all text file symlink pointers to replace `_F-ss` with empty string as below but running into below error, any guidance on how to fix this?

```
find . -name "*.txt" -type l | xargs 'ln -nsf "$(readlink "%p" | sed s/_F-ss//)"'
```

Error:-

```
xargs: ln -nsf "$(readlink "%p" | sed s/_F-ss//)": No such file or directory
```

Comment: `$(..)` is not expanded under single quotes, double quote it

Comment: @Inian - you mean like `find . -name "*.txt" -type l | xargs "ln -nsf "$(readlink "%p" | sed s/_F-ss//)""`

Comment: it throws the erorr `xargs: ln -nsf : No such file or directory`

Comment: You can drop the outer quotes and just do `find . -name "*.txt" -type l | xargs ln -nsf "$(readlink "%p" | sed s/_F-ss//)"`

Comment: No errors but that didnt update the symlinks

Comment: Can you try `find . -name "*.txt" -type l | xargs -I {} bash -c 'ln -nsf {} "$(readlink "%p" | sed s/_F-ss//)"' `

Comment: that didn't help ,BTW I am running this on a mac

Comment: This should (hopefully) `find . -name "*.txt" -type l -exec ln -s '{}' "$(readlink "%p" | sed s/_F-ss//)" ';'`

Comment: I keep getting `ln: : No such file or directory`

Comment: Does `find . -name "*.txt" -type l` return any results at all?

Comment: yes,it shows all the symlink .txt files

Comment: What about `echo "$(readlink "%p" | sed s/_F-ss//)"`

Comment: I ran `find . -name "*.txt" -type l -exec echo "$(readlink "%p" | sed s/_F-ss//)" \;` ,it printed a bunch of empty lines

Comment: So the whole problem is your `"$(readlink "%p" | sed s/_F-ss//)"` is empty.

Comment: wondering why because `readlink P-maldives-X3_M-TPHN_V-u__m-3.3.txt` shows 
`P-maldives_M-TPHN_V-u_F-ss__m-3.3.txt`

Comment: Which directory are you running this from? Are you running with %p and it is working?

Comment: I ran a seperate command as `readlink P-maldives-X3_M-TPHN_V-u__m-3.3.txt | sed 's/_F-ss//g'`  and it works,am running it from a directory which has all *.txt files

Comment: what does `%p` do here?

Comment: Get `readlink "%p" | sed s/_F-ss//` working first. Then get `ln -nsf "$(readlink "%p" | sed s/_F-ss//)"` working. THEN try it with `find | xargs`

Comment: `readlink "%p"` seems to be one thats causing this,why is `%p` not taking the find output

Comment: I think the part in `$(..)` is executed before `find`. Can you try 
`find . -name "*.txt" -type l  |  xargs -L1 readlink | sed 's/_F-ss//' | xargs -L1 ln -nsf`

Comment: @wisecrack `readlink` takes a file name as an argument. You aren't giving it a file name as an argument but you are giving it a string `"%p"` as an argument which may or may not be desirable. See [my earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63622366/how-to-batch-update-all-symlink-pointers-to-replace-f-ss-with-empty-string#comment112506627_63622366) for how to make progress.